# Lombok not visible during building project IntelliJ 13.1

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

I use Intellij Idea 13.1.5 BUILD 135.1289 with my maven project using lombok:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

While when I inspect my entity class used with spring-data-neo4j annotations:

```
 @Data
@NodeEntity
public class EmployeeBase {

    @GraphId
    private Long nodeID;

    private Integer neo_eb_id;...
```

When I try to Alt+Insert to create get/set methods  i get message that all methods exists for all fields. But when I run mvn clean packge i get the message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] mediator/domain/dao/impl/strategies/EmployeeDAO_Neo4j.java:[38,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getNeo_eb_id()
[ERROR] location: variable u of type phd.chromiak.dias.mediator.domain.model.EmployeeBase
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Which actually is added with Intellij Alt+Space hint context menu.

The setting "Enable annotation processing" in Settings->Compiler->Annotation Processors. i checked but it does not change anything.

**How can I fix this to use lombok back again?**

Comment: Does it work when you rename the field with camel case to `neoEbId`?

Comment: Following the Java naming convention probably helps. Any reason you're using [an ancient version of Lombok](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok)?

Comment: Changing to `private Integer neoEbId;` did not helped.
Lombok 0.12 is the newest i get from maven artefact search in intellij. Don't know why.

Comment: @Szczepan Try updating the Maven repositories from Settings/Maven/Repositories/Update and you should get autocompletion for newer versions of Maven artifacts.

Comment: There's Lombok plugin for IDEA, install that as well.

Comment: @ Bohuslav Burghardt I just did it still show the old versions.
I have lombok plugin enabled settings->lombok plugin